# WordPress does not load most theme images

Tags: images, themes

I am self-hosting a WordPress website, which I'm trying to customize properly. When I choose a theme in the Appearance menu, I see a preview of the theme, which is as it should be (please see below). However, when I activate the theme, most images simply do not appear (the second picture below).

I don't know how to properly approach this issue, would appreciate some advice.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You will need to ask the theme author how to configure the theme to look like the screenshot. Theme screenshots are just examples of how it can look when populated with content. It won't look like that when activated on an empty site, and probably doesn't include the images in the screenshot for your use.

Comment: @JacobPeattie This seems to apply to all themes. Is it the same for you too?

Comment: Yes, it will be the same for most themes. Some come with demo content, but far from all of them.

Comment: Incredible, and I thought it was a technical issue on my side :-)